# Why does reduction of order work for linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Specifically, if we know that one solution is $y_1(t)$, then why is the second solution in the form $y_2(t) = v(t) y_1(t)$?  Where $v(t)$ is the function that you need to solve for.  Why does this assumption always work?

Answer (score 8):

This is a *differential* analog of the Factor Theorem. Let's recall the latter first. If $\rm\:x = r\:$ is a root of the polynomial $\rm\:p(x)\:$ over a ring R, then by the Division Algorithm we have

$$\rm p(x) = (x-r)\:q(x) + c,\ \ for\ \  c\in R,\ \ \ so\ \ \ p(r)=0\ \iff\ \ c = 0$$

Now consider a linear differential equation presented in *operator form* using $\rm\:D = \frac{d}{dx}\:$

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} &&\rm\ a_n f^{(n)} +\,\cdots\,+ a_1 f' + a_0\ f\ =\ 0\quad\ where\ \ a_i\ may\ depend\ on\ x\\
 &\to\ &\rm (a_n D^n +\, \cdots\, + a_1 D + a_0)(f) = 0\end{eqnarray}$$

Let $\rm\:L = L(D)\:$ denote the above polynomial in $\rm\:D.\:$  Products of such polynomials generally do not commute because $\rm\:D\:$ does not commute with $\rm\:x,\:$ indeed $\rm\:  Dx = xD + 1\:$ as operators, since $\rm\: (D\cdot x)f = D(xf) = x(Df) + f = (x\cdot D+1)f.\:$ However, there are certain specialized type of division algorithms available for these noncommutative polynomials, as Oystein Ore worked out in detail. In particular, if you work out the product of $\rm\:L(fg)\:$ in general as in Robert's answer you will obtain

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm (L\cdot f)g &=&\rm  L(fg) = (\hat L\cdot  D) g + (Lf) g\\ 
\rm i.e.\quad L\cdot f &=&\rm \hat L\cdot D + Lf\ \ \ for\ \ \hat L\ \ of\ smaller\ degree\ (order)\ in\ D\end{eqnarray} $$

In effect we right-divided $\rm\:L\cdot f\:$ by $\rm\:D\:$ with $\rm\:Lf = $ remainder. Thus  when $\rm\:Lf = 0,\:$ i.e. when $\rm\:f\:$ is a solution of $\rm\:L,\:$ we deduce $\rm\:L(fg) = 0 \iff \hat L(Dg) = 0,\:$ yielding the *reduction of order*.

Reduction of order is sometimes called D'Alembert's method. You can find modern algorithmic work on such by searching on that name and Abramov and Petkovsek - two of many researchers who have generalized Ore's work to effective algorithms employed in computer algebra systems.

Answer (score 4):

Any function $y_2(t)$ can be written as $v(t) y_1(t)$, at least on an interval where $y_1(t) \ne 0$: you just take $v(t) = y_2(t)/y_1(t)$. The real question is, how does this substitution help?  The answer to that  comes from linearity and Leibniz's rule for differentiation: 
$$ (v y_1)^{(n)} = v y_1^{(n)} + \text{terms in $v', v'', \ldots, v^{(n)}$}$$ 
If you have a linear differential equation is $L(y) = 0$ of order $m$, the first terms give you $v L(y_1) = 0$,
and you are left with a linear differential equation involving $v', \ldots, v^{(m)}$ from the other terms; this is still a linear differential equation in $v$ of order $m$, but since
there is no term in $v$ (without any differentiation) it can be written as a linear differential equation in $v'$ of order $m-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it with a differential equation of degree $3-$ this will make it obvious
why it works for a differential equation of any degree:
$$
(y)^{\prime \prime \prime}+o(x)(y)^{\prime \prime}+p(x)(y)^{\prime}+q(x) y=0
$$

We know that $y_{1}$ is a solution, and we look for solutions of the form $y_{2}(x)=$
$v(x) y_{1}(x) .$ There is nothing special about doing this - and, I'm not sure what
the original motivation behind it was (could have just been plain-luck), but,
for any equation, if a solution $y_{1}(x)$ exists that is non-zero in the interval
under consideration, a solution $y_{2}(x)=v(x) y_{1}(x)$ will exist as well.

Explicitly constructed, the function
$v(x)=\frac{y_{2}(x)}{y_{1}(x)}$ will give us that solution (which shows why its important for $y_1(x)$ to be non-zero).

Anyways, let's try out our solution.
$$
\left(v y_{1}\right)^{\prime \prime \prime}+o(x)\left(v y_{1}\right)^{\prime \prime}+p(x)\left(v y_{1}\right)^{\prime}+q(x) v y_{1}=0
$$

Using the Leibniz Rule for Differentiation (not differentiation under the
integral sign - the other one where we use Pascal's Triangle for the coefficients) we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\left(v^{\prime \prime \prime} y_{1}+3 v^{\prime \prime} y_{1}^{\prime}+3 v^{\prime} y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+v y_{1}^{\prime \prime \prime}\right)+o(x)\left(v y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+2 v^{\prime} y_{1}^{\prime}+v^{\prime \prime} y_{1}\right) \\
+p(x)\left(v y_{1}^{\prime}+v^{\prime} y_{1}\right)+q(x) v y_{1}=0
\end{array}
$$
Putting together terms, we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
v^{\prime \prime \prime} y_{1}+v^{\prime \prime}\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime}+o(x) y_{1}\right)+v^{\prime}\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+o(x) 2 y_{1}^{\prime}+p(x) y_{1}\right) \\
+v\left(y_{1}^{\prime \prime \prime}+o(x) y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+p(x) y_{1}^{\prime}+q(x) y_{1}\right)=0
\end{array}
$$
And, once more, the last term (crossed-out) is zero... which leaves us with:
$$
v^{\prime \prime \prime} y_{1}+v^{\prime \prime}\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime}+o(x) y_{1}\right)+v^{\prime}\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+o(x) 2 y_{1}^{\prime}+p(x) y_{1}\right)=0
$$
Then, we let $w(x)=v^{\prime}(x)$, and we get:
$$
w^{\prime \prime} y_{1}+w^{\prime}\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime}+o(x) y_{1}\right)+w\left(3 y_{1}^{\prime \prime}+o(x) 2 y_{1}^{\prime}+p(x) y_{1}\right)=0
$$
And thus, we've reduced the order!

In the general case, it's easy to see that when we differentiate using the Leibniz
Rule, all the terms are associated with $v(x)$ will not have any of the "Pascal's Triangle coefficients" (or whatever they're called) on
them, and thus we'll get our original equation back!