# How to solve a second-order ODE without guessing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

In the case of a homogeneous second-order ODE with repeated roots, for example,
$$
y''+4y'+4y=0
$$
a candidate solution would be obtainable by finding a function $v(x)$ such that
$$
y=Ae^{\lambda x}+v(x)e^{\lambda x}
$$
solves the equation. We eventually get $v(x)=Bx$. My question is: how can we work out that it needs to be a function multiplying by $e^{\lambda x}$? In other words, where does this guess come from?

In the case of non-repeated roots, [this is a nice way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4041766/487230) of showing where the candidate $Ae^{\lambda_1 x}+Be^{\lambda_2 x}$, but I am struggling to see the case of repeated roots. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this equation can be transformed to $(e^{2x}y(x))''=0$. It depends on your taste if the finding of integrating factors for linear DE counts as guessing.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is *reduction of order*. See this question, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235855/why-does-reduction-of-order-work-for-linear-odes

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the ODE
$$
y''+4y'+4y=0 \tag{1}
$$
using a method similar to the one used in the post linked to your question. Let's rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
(D^2+4D+4)y=(D+2)(D+2)y=0, \tag{2}
$$
where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. Equation $(2)$ is equivalent to the pair of first order ODEs
\begin{align}
(D+2)u&=0, \tag{3} \\
(D+2)y&=u. \tag{4}
\end{align}
The solution to $(3)$ is $u=C_1e^{-2x}$; plugging this result into $(4)$, we obtain
$$
(D+2)y=C_1e^{-2x} \implies e^{2x}(D+2)y=C_1 \implies D(e^{2x}y)=C_1
$$
$$
\implies e^{2x}y=C_1x+C_2 \implies y=(C_1x+C_2)e^{-2x}.\quad{\square} \tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You could figure it out via solving with Laplace transform (it comes form frequency shifting):

$$
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y^{\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y\left( s \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

Taking the Laplace transform:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\left\{ y^{\prime\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y^{\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y\left( s \right) \right\}\left( s \right) &= \mathcal{L}\left\{ 0 \right\}\left( s \right)\\
\mathcal{L}\left\{ y^{\prime\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y^{\prime}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot y\left( s \right) \right\}\left( s \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now using the fact that the Laplace transform is linear:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\left\{ y^{\prime\prime}\left( s \right) \right\}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot \mathcal{L}\left\{ y^{\prime}\left( s \right) \right\}\left( s \right) + 4 \cdot \mathcal{L}\left\{ y\left(sx \right) \right\}\left( s \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

Let's define $y\left( 0 \right) = c_{1}$ and $y'\left( 0 \right) = c_{2}$ and use $\mathcal{L}\left\{ y^{\left( n \right)}\left( s \right) \right\}\left( s \right) = s^{n} \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}\left[ s^{n - k} \cdot y^{\left( k - 1 \right)}\left( 0 \right) \right]$:
$$
\begin{align*}
s^{2} \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) - c_{2} - s \cdot c_{1} + 4 \cdot s \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) - 4 \cdot c_{1} + 4 \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) &= 0\\
\left( s^{2} + 4 \cdot s + 4 \right) \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) - c_{2} - \left( s + 4 \right) \cdot c_{1} &= 0\\
\left( s + 2 \right)^{2} \cdot y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) - c_{2} - \left( s + 4 \right) \cdot c_{1} &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

Solving for $y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right)$ and taking the inverse Laplace transform:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ y_{\mathcal{L}}\left( s \right) \right\}\left( x \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{c_{2} + \left( s + 4 \right) \cdot c_{1}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{c_{2}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right) + \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{\left( s + 4 \right) \cdot c_{1}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= c_{2} \cdot x \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x}+ \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{\left( s + 2 \right) \cdot c_{1} + 2 \cdot c_{1}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= c_{2} \cdot x \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x} + \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{\left( s + 2 \right) \cdot c_{1}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right) + 2 \cdot \mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{c_{1}}{\left( s + 2 \right)^{2}} \right\}\left( x \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= c_{2} \cdot x \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x} + c_{1} \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x} + 2 \cdot c_{1} \cdot x \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x}\\
y\left( x \right) &= \left( c_{1} + \left( c_{2} + 2 \cdot c_{1} \right) \cdot x \right) \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

If $c_{1} =:  A$ and $c_{2} + 2 \cdot c_{1} =: B$, we get your solution.